# Como hacer una condicion en map dependiendo de la posición del array en React

Tags: reactjs, bucle-for, algoritmos, map

He estado probando un rato, casi una hora supongo para hacer un map que dependiendo de cada cierto número del index del array coloque un nuevo elemento:

```
class productos extends React.Component {
  render() {
  const arr = [
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 1 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 2 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 3 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 4 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 5 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 6 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 7 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 8 },
  ]
 
  var num = 0;
    
    return (
        <div>
        {
          arr.map(items => {
                if(num === num * 4){
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <h3> Producto </h3>
                        <p>{items.name}</p>
                        <p>{items.img}</p>
                        <p>{items.id}</p>
                      <br/>
                      {num + 1}
                     </div>
                    )
                }else{
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <p>{items.legth}</p>
                      <p>{items.img}</p>
                      <p>{items.id}</p>
                        <br/>
                      {num + 1}
                    </div>
                  )
                }
              }
            )
          }
      </div>
      )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <FriendsContainer />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Creo que las condiciones están bien implementadas, pero el problema nace ne como poder guardar el número de la variable "num". Si hay una manera de guardar el nuevo valor de la misma, creo que el código no presentara más problemas y podrá mostrar el "h2" y luego cuatro "items".

¿Quizás con un for funciona?

```
class productos extends React.Component {
  render() {
  const arr = [
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 1 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 2 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 3 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 4 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 5 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 6 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 7 },
    { name: 'pollo', img: 'img.jpg', id: 8 },
  ]
 
  var num = 0;
    
    return (
        <div>
          {
          for(var i = 0; i < arr.leght; i++)
            {
              if(i === i * 4) {
                <div>
                  <h3> Producto </h3>
                  <p>{items.name}</p>
                  <p>{items.img}</p>
                  <p>{items.id}</p>
                  <br/>
                </div>
              } else {
                return(
                  <div>
                    <p>{items.name}</p>
                    <p>{items.img}</p>
                    <p>{items.id}</p>
                    <br/>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            }
        }
        </div>
      )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <FriendsContainer />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Lo intente, pero me sale el error de unexpected tokens en la línea del "for", un clásico. Creo que en React es diferente la forma de implementarlo y creo que con un for será la forma correcta de resolver el algoritmo.

Resumiendo, necesito que el algoritmo cada 4 "items" renderice el respectivo "h2" para poder hacer una separación por cada 4 "items". Cualquier tipo de solución es bienvenida, en React por favor. De antemano, ¡¡muchas Gracias!!

Comment: El primer ejemplo funciona tal y como describes la situación, ¿Pero tu quieres resolverlo con un `for` como en el segundo ejemplo?

Comment: El primer ejemplo funciona, pero no con los resultados esperados, hace un momento se me ocurrió cambiar la variable por un state, pero no me llego al resultado esperado que es cada 4 "items" aparezca el "h2", el primero funciona, pero no cumple la condición, el for directamente no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El algoritmo tiene una secuencia definida de cada **4 items**, una forma de resolverlo es buscando los **números múltiplos de 4** en la iteración del `array`:

> Para saber si un número es múltiplo de otro, se debe hacer la división y comprobar que el cociente es un número natural y el resto de la división es cero.

Ahora, se puede saber el resto de una división con el operador [reminder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) de Javascript:

> JS: divisor % Dividendo = resto

Además, se puede saber el `índice` del elemento de un array dentro de una operación `map`, solo hay que incluirlo en los argumentos del `callback`:

```
array.map((item,index)=>console.log(index));
```

Entonces, siendo `index` el **divisor** y `4` el **Dividendo**, la operación del algoritmo es:

> index % 4 = 0

Demo JSX:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const arr = [
      { name: 'pollo 1', img: 'img.jpg', id: 1 },
      { name: 'pollo 2', img: 'img.jpg', id: 2 },
      { name: 'pollo 3', img: 'img.jpg', id: 3 },
      { name: 'pollo 4', img: 'img.jpg', id: 4 },
      { name: 'pollo 5', img: 'img.jpg', id: 5 },
      { name: 'pollo 6', img: 'img.jpg', id: 6 },
      { name: 'pollo 7', img: 'img.jpg', id: 7 },
      { name: 'pollo 8', img: 'img.jpg', id: 8 },
      { name: 'pollo 9', img: 'img.jpg', id: 9 },
      { name: 'pollo 10', img: 'img.jpg', id: 10 },
      { name: 'pollo 11', img: 'img.jpg', id: 11 },
      { name: 'pollo 12', img: 'img.jpg', id: 12 },
    ];
    
  return (
      <div>
      {
        arr.map((items, index) => {
              if(index % 4 === 0){
                return (
                  <div key={items.id}>
                    <h3> Producto </h3>
                      <p>{items.name}</p>
                      <p>{items.img}</p>
                      <p>{items.id}</p>
                    <br/>
                  </div>
                  )
              }else{
                return (
                  <div key={items.id}>
                    <p>{items.name}</p>
                    <p>{items.img}</p>
                    <p>{items.id}</p>
                      <br/>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            }
          )
        }
    </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

---

Enlaces relacionados:

[Múltiplos de un número 1](https://matematicascercanas.com/2020/09/08/multiplos-de-un-numero/)

[Múltiplos de un número 2](http://agrega.educacion.es/repositorio/03122014/3c/es_2014120312_9201222/mltiplos_y_divisores_de_un_nmero.html)